# spring - how to deny the direct access to servlet mapping(POST method used) from the url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

For example, I have a servlet mapping /servlet, and actually it is requested by a form using POST Method. If I type in the mapping directly without using the form in the browser, the server will give me a 405 page.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

What I want to do is to catch this exception using spring security. I was thinking to restrict this servelet request by using POST method only so that the direct url access will be denied. However, I searched on the internet but I didn't find an answer. Please guide me how to do this, thanks.

Comment: If you are getting 405 error it means this url is restricted to be used by pody method only means direct url access is denied. What i couldn't understand is now what else you want to achieve. Do you want to display some customized error message to user instead of this 405 error message?

Comment: YES, you are right, I just want to display some customized error message

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override default error message you should create your own error page and map it into web.xml like this

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/internal-server-error.htm</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/405.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and your 405.html will contain your personalized error message for the user.

Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-error-page-in-j2ee/26770